# How to set PITR for all databases in a Azure Sql Database Elastic Pool?

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, powershell-5.0

I think I'm running into version issues because the cmdlet I want seems to only be available in `AzureRM.Sql` module version `4.7.0-preview`.

I want to set the PITR retention policy for many databases in an elastic pool to 35 days. By default my vCore pool has a retention policy of 7 days which is not enough. I have hundreds of databases so need to set them all with PowerShell.

If I get the list of databases to update with `Get-AzureRmSqlElasticPoolDatabase` and then try to run `Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseBackupShortTermRetentionPolicy` I get this error when running the latter:

```
import-module : The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Error in TypeData "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Replication.Model.AzureSqlDatabaseCopyModel": The member DefaultDisplayPropertySet is already present.
Error in TypeData "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Replication.Model.AzureReplicationLinkModel": The member DefaultDisplayPropertySet is already present.

At line:1 char:1
+ import-module azurerm.sql
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

**Things I've tried**

I've tried removing the module and re-importing it. Same error.
I've tried importing the required version of the module and getting the database list with the first command but I then get this error:

```
Get-AzureRmSqlElasticPoolDatabase : The 'Get-AzureRmSqlElasticPoolDatabase' command was found in the module 'AzureRM.Sql', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module AzureRM.Sql'.
At line:1 char:8
+ $dbs = Get-AzureRmSqlElasticPoolDatabase -ElasticPoolName $settings.E ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureRmSqlElasticPoolDatabase:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

If I import the AzureRm module with `import-module azurerm.sql` I get this error:

```
import-module : The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Error in TypeData "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Replication.Model.AzureSqlDatabaseCopyModel": The member DefaultDisplayPropertySet is already present.
Error in TypeData "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Replication.Model.AzureReplicationLinkModel": The member DefaultDisplayPropertySet is already present.

At line:1 char:1
+ import-module azurerm.sql
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

**Modules**

`Get-Module AzureRm -ListAvailable | select Name, Version`:

```
Name    Version
----    -------
AzureRM 6.10.0
```

`Get-Module AzureRm.Sql -ListAvailable | select Name, Version`:

```
Name        Version
----        -------
AzureRM.Sql 4.11.5
AzureRM.Sql 4.7.0
AzureRM.Sql 4.4.0
```

`$PSVersionTable`:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.228
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.228
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to install `4.11.4-preview` version of `AzureRM.Sql` module, refer to this [link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Sql/4.11.4-preview), use `Install-Module -Name AzureRM.Sql -RequiredVersion 4.11.4-preview -AllowPrerelease` in the powershell administrator environment.

After installing it, no need to import module, you could excute the command straightly. If you want to check the module if installs successfully, navigate to `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM.Sql`, you will find a `4.11.4` folder.

Then try the sample command to set PITR for all databases in a Elastic Pool , it works fine on my side.(You could execute `Get-Help Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseBackupShortTermRetentionPolicy` to get the usage of the command)

```
$dbs = Get-AzureRmSqlElasticPoolDatabase -ResourceGroupName "joywebapp" -ServerName "joydb" -ElasticPoolName "joyelastic"
foreach($db in $dbs){
    Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseBackupShortTermRetentionPolicy -ResourceGroupName $db.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $db.ServerName -DatabaseName $db.DatabaseName -RetentionDays 35
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks what version of AzureRm module do you have? I think that's the module that is conflicted.

Comment: I removed AzureRM completely. I checked the Modules directly and deleted everything related to Azure in it. I then installed AzureRM 6.10 (the default) and then AzureRM.Sql 4.11.4-preview. When I `import-module azurerm.sql -RequiredVersion 4.11.4` I get the error again.

Comment: @MarkAllison My AzureRm version seems to be 5.6, I am not sure, I am using mobile to reply to you. But you should note that I do not execute import module command after installing the AzureRm.Sql module, you could have a try.

Comment: Thanks I will try an older version of AzureRm and try that. Running without Import-Module results in PowerShell not finding the command to set the RetentionPolicy. CMdlet not found.

Comment: @MarkAllison Glad to hear that.^_^