# Azure PowerShell not working inside Azure Dev Ops on private agent

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-rm

I have installed a 64-bit private agent on my Windows Server 2012 R2 build server. I have connected this to Azure Dev Ops. On the build server I only have version 5.6.0 of AzureRM installed because that is required for the scripts I want to run. See my other Q for the reasons if you're interested: [How to set PITR for all databases in a Azure Sql Database Elastic Pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879213/how-to-set-pitr-for-all-databases-in-a-azure-sql-database-elastic-pool)

If I create an Azure PowerShell v3 task in Azure DevOps to run the following inline script:

`Get-Module -Name AzureRM* -ListAvailable`

I get this error:

```
2018-11-14T13:26:56.0519566Z ==============================================================================
2018-11-14T13:26:56.0519655Z Task         : Azure PowerShell
2018-11-14T13:26:56.0519727Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
2018-11-14T13:26:56.0519782Z Version      : 3.1.7
2018-11-14T13:26:56.0519844Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-11-14T13:26:56.0520315Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613749)
2018-11-14T13:26:56.0520404Z ==============================================================================
2018-11-14T13:26:57.1508635Z Added TLS 1.2 in session.
2018-11-14T13:26:57.4439615Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM\5.6.0\AzureRM.psd1 -Global
2018-11-14T13:26:58.6759005Z ##[error]The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Error in TypeData "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IAzureContextContainer": The TypeConverter was ignored because it already occurs.
Error in TypeData "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IAzureContextContainer": The member SerializationDepth is already present.
Error in TypeData "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ProtectedFileTokenCache": The member PropertySerializationSet is already present.
Error in TypeData "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ProtectedFileTokenCache": The member SerializationMethod is already present.
Error in TypeData "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AuthenticationStoreTokenCache": The member PropertySerializationSet is already present.
Error in TypeData "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AuthenticationStoreTokenCache": The member SerializationMethod is already present.
Error in TypeData "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureContext": The member SerializationDepth is already present.
Error in TypeData "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureProfile": The member SerializationDepth is already present.
```

If I log on to the build server as the build server account and open a PowerShell window it works fine. It also works fine in a normal PowerShell task in Azure DevOps.

My PowerShell script needs to run in the context of an Azure Account, how can I achieve that?

**EDIT**

I've tried Azure PowerShell tasks v1 and v2 and that didn't work. I also tried specifying the PowerShell version in the version options part as version 5.6 and also Latest installed version. Neither of those worked.

Comment: probably related to the module version, try updating module version? or specify your azure powershell version in the build step settings

Comment: As mentioned in my Q, I can't change the module version.

Comment: thanks see my edit

Comment: You may want to check what version of PowerShell you are running on your private server, you can check Get-Host and get the version number.

Comment: @Iain 5.1.14409.1012